# How to retrieve issuer alternative name for ssl certificate by openssl

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I can get the subject alternative name like

```
 X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID(X509_get_subject_name(x), NID_subject_alt_name, hc->https_domain_name, 256)
```

With same method by changing 2. parameter to **NID_issuer_alt_name** I am expecting to get issuer name like;

```
X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID(X509_get_subject_name(x), NID_issuer_alt_name, hc->https_ca_name, 256);
```

But instead I am getting a empty string . How can I retrieve issuer alternative name correctly?

Comment: Please check if the given certificate has issuer alternate name. I think it is an extension.

Comment: You should **not** be using `X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID` because it suffers from Marlinspike's embedded `NULL` tricks. From the OpenSSL docs (which fails to mention the vulnerability): "`X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID` or `X509_NAME_get_index_by_OBJ` should be used followed by `X509_NAME_get_entry`"

Comment: Also see OpenSSL's wiki page on [Hostname Validation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the following solution, as recommended in https://github.com/iSECPartners/ssl-conservatory :

```
static HostnameValidationResult matches_subject_alternative_name (const char *hostname, const X509 *server_cert) {
    HostnameValidationResult result = MatchNotFound;
    int i;
    int san_names_nb = -1;
    STACK_OF(GENERAL_NAME) *san_names = NULL;

    // Try to extract the names within the SAN extension from the certificate
    san_names = X509_get_ext_d2i((X509 *) server_cert, NID_subject_alt_name, NULL, NULL);
    if (san_names == NULL) {
        return NoSANPresent;
    }
    san_names_nb = sk_GENERAL_NAME_num(san_names);

    // Check each name within the extension
    for (i=0; i<san_names_nb; i++) {
        const GENERAL_NAME *current_name = sk_GENERAL_NAME_value(san_names, i);

        if (current_name->type == GEN_DNS) {
            // Current name is a DNS name, let's check it
            char *dns_name = (char *) ASN1_STRING_data(current_name->d.dNSName);

            // Make sure there isn't an embedded NUL character in the DNS name
            if (ASN1_STRING_length(current_name->d.dNSName) != strlen(dns_name)) {
                result = MalformedCertificate;
                break;
            }
            else { // Compare expected hostname with the DNS name
                if (strcasecmp(hostname, dns_name) == 0) {
                    result = MatchFound;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sk_GENERAL_NAME_pop_free(san_names, GENERAL_NAME_free);

    return result;
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: As I understand this is for getting subject alternative name . I need   issuer alternative name .

Comment: Try to replace `NID_subject_alt_name` with `NID_issuer_alt_name`, I'll try to do this on my PC now and see how it works for me.

Comment: You mean like that right , X509_get_ext_d2i((X509 *) server_cert, NID_issuer_alt_name, NULL, NULL) . I tried still empty string thanks for advice though.

Comment: Beware of a potential null pointer dereference. `sk_GENERAL_NAME_value()` calls `sk_value` which can return `NULL`. However your pointer `current_name` is not checked for NULL before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 0):

In your call to X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID with the NID_issuer_alt_name constant, I would have replaced X509_get_subject_name(x) by X509_get_issuer_name(x). I think this should do the trick you are after.